Arabic grammar in Antlr 4
i wanted to create a simple test, to see if its possible to create a small and simple programming language but with arabic words that are the equivelant to words like: print, variable, function and so one in english, after reading through parts of the antlr manual and also searching here i could not find an answer to the following question, in arabic we have use diffrent letters but also a diffrent way to write numbers so ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ instead of 0123456789, i managed to make it work on mac os, with the following tools: intelji IDE, antlr package refered to on the antlr4 website for the intelji ide, and also used the ANTLR 4.13.2 Java runtime binaries jar. but it causes a lot of issues on windows:
here is the code i used to test, used it both in windows and mac os:
ArabicLang.g4: grammar ArabicLang;

prog:   statement* EOF;

statement
    :   declareStatement
    |   assignStatement
    |   printStatement
    |   ifStatement
    ;

declareStatement
    :   'متغير' VAR_NAME '؛'
    ;

assignStatement
    :   VAR_NAME '=' expr '؛'
    ;

printStatement
    :   'طباعة' VAR_NAME '؛'
    ;

ifStatement
    :   'إذا' '(' expr ')' '{' statement* '}'
    ;

expr
    :   expr '+' expr
    |   expr '-' expr
    |   expr '*' expr
    |   expr '/' expr
    |   expr '<' expr
    |   expr '>' expr
    |   expr '==' expr
    |   expr '!=' expr
    |   expr '&&' expr
    |   expr '||' expr
    |   INT
    |   VAR_NAME
    ;

VAR_NAME
    :   [\u0621-\u064A]+;

INT
    :   [٠-٩]+;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;


ArabicIntrepeter.java: package src;



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ArabicInterpreter extends ArabicLangBaseVisitor<Object> {

    private Map<String, Integer> symbolTable = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Boolean> declaredVariables = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object visitDeclareStatement(ArabicLangParser.DeclareStatementContext ctx) {
        String varName = ctx.VAR_NAME().getText();
        if (declaredVariables.containsKey(varName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("متغير مُعلن بالفعل: " + varName);
        }
        declaredVariables.put(varName, true);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitAssignStatement(ArabicLangParser.AssignStatementContext ctx) {
        String varName = ctx.VAR_NAME().getText();
        if (!declaredVariables.containsKey(varName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("متغير غير مُعلن: " + varName);
        }
        int value = (int) visit(ctx.expr());
        symbolTable.put(varName, value);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitPrintStatement(ArabicLangParser.PrintStatementContext ctx) {
        String varName = ctx.VAR_NAME().getText();
        if (!symbolTable.containsKey(varName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("متغير غير مُعرف: " + varName);
        }
        System.out.println(symbolTable.get(varName));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitIfStatement(ArabicLangParser.IfStatementContext ctx) {
        int condition = (int) visit(ctx.expr());
        if (condition != 0) {
            for (ArabicLangParser.StatementContext statementCtx : ctx.statement()) {
                visit(statementCtx);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitExpr(ArabicLangParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.INT() != null) {
            return Integer.parseInt(ctx.INT().getText());
        } else if (ctx.VAR_NAME() != null) {
            String varName = ctx.VAR_NAME().getText();
            if (!declaredVariables.containsKey(varName)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("متغير غير مُعلن: " + varName);
            }
            if (!symbolTable.containsKey(varName)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("متغير غير مُهيأ: " + varName);
            }
            return symbolTable.get(varName);
        } else {
            int left = (int) visit(ctx.expr(0));
            int right = (int) visit(ctx.expr(1));
            switch (ctx.getChild(1).getText()) {
                case "+":
                    return left + right;
                case "-":
                    return left - right;
                case "*":
                    return left * right;
                case "/":
                    return left / right;
                case "<":
                    return left < right ? 1 : 0;
                case ">":
                    return left > right ? 1 : 0;
                case "==":
                    return left == right ? 1 : 0;
                case "!=":
                    return left != right ? 1 : 0;
                case "&&":
                    return (left != 0 && right != 0) ? 1 : 0;
                case "||":
                    return (left != 0 || right != 0) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }
        return 0; // Default return (not reachable)
    }
}


import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import src.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ArabicLangMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Define the file path (fixed file "source.arabic")
        String filePath = "source.arabic";

        // Read the source code from the file
        String source = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));

        // Create an ANTLR input stream from the source code
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromString(source);

        // Create a lexer that feeds off of the input stream
        ArabicLangLexer lexer = new ArabicLangLexer(input);

        // Create a buffer of tokens between the lexer and parser
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        // Create a parser that feeds off the tokens
        ArabicLangParser parser = new ArabicLangParser(tokens);

        // Parse the program
        ParseTree tree = parser.prog();

        // Visit the parse tree using the interpreter
        ArabicInterpreter interpreter = new ArabicInterpreter();
        interpreter.visit(tree);
    }
}


source.arabic: 
متغير عدد؛
عدد = ٣؛
طباعة عدد؛
متغير مجموع؛
مجموع = عدد * ٢؛
طباعة مجموع؛
مجموع = عدد - ١؛
طباعة مجموع؛
مجموع = عدد / ٢؛
طباعة مجموع؛


Instead of Files.readAllBytes(Path), you might try your luck with CharStreams.fromFileName(Path), which defaults to utf-8. Or you could change the constructor for String(byte[]), instead using public String​(byte[] bytes, String charsetName) with "UTF-8" or some such charset name. The file should probably have no BOM.
